# CUDA toolkit seems intal but tensorflow don't see GPU

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, tensorflow

I have a laptop with an RTX3060, I use tensorflow >= 2.6.0 on ubuntu 20.04.
I have installed nvidia drivers version 495.44

I installed dependencies following tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).
I have installed cuda 11.5 in `/usr/local/cuda-11.5` and cudNN for cuda 11.5 and set path in zshrc.

When I import tensorflow in a program I have no warnings/errors but when I try to list them I have this :

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2021-11-30 16:51:37.873669: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:939] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-11-30 16:51:37.895854: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.5/include:/usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib64:
2021-11-30 16:51:37.895881: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Does anyone know why tensorflow still don't see my GPU ?

Comment: Seems odd to have an include dir in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but the libcudnn.so should have been found in the second part -- so where is it?  Use locate libcudnn.so to find it. How did you install it?

Comment: @ubfan1 I use .deb file from nvidia official website. Yes in fact libcuddn was in /usr/lib/cuda/lib64, I add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it's working.